# Social media for a mathematics related idea buckets

Tags: recreational-mathematics, mathematical-writing, online-resources

Are there any good social media platforms that can recommended for communicating ideas related to mathematics?

The reason for asking is that I am in the situation that, albeit having studied math, I am not a professional mathematician and enjoy ruminating about mathematical problems from which I get the one or other insight I would like to share with others.
As I see it that neither fits the policy of MO or stackexchange that are dedicated to asking and answering questions that meet certain criteria.
ArXiv is too restrictive and vixRa too permissive and potentially harmful to reputation.
Setting up an own website or blog is too much overhead for my taste.

So I would like hear of recommendations for social media sites that could be suitable for what I envisage and

- support mathematical type setting
- allow for tagging
- allow for embedding downloadable documents
- be frequented by "educated" people
- have some permanence
- have no negative (impact on) reputation

Comment: A certain cohort of mathematicians liked to use Google plus for short blog-ish posts but it was permanently deleted.

Comment: Isn't this what researchgate is trying to be? But a personal web page is not that difficult to set up, once the initial system is in place.

Comment: A blog is not so difficult these days.

Comment: A blog is not exactly a "social media"

Comment: "idea buckets"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind by saying "social media", e.g. I wouldn't usually think of arXiv as "social media" at all.  Certainly a blog is at least as "social" as arXiv.  Have you tried Zulip?  It's a slack-like chat interface that supports math typesetting.  It requires a dedicated "server" to be set up for any given community, but there are already a number of zulip servers set up for different mathematical subjects that are frequented by plenty of "educated" mathematicians.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what is the question you're asking?
What I mean by idea bucket: sometimes I don't have the time or resources to investigate upon a promising idea, but maybe others can draw inspiration from it - I don't know if it is a valid comparison, but maybe the benefit is the same as that communicating conjectures in the field of mathematics.

Comment: @MikeShulman by "social media" I mean something like FB but with deeper waters and higher moral standards. I'm not so convinced by setting up a blog because in some sense blogging means waiting for people to come whereas using using social media means going to where the people are (sorry for the naive clarification of the difference I see).

Comment: Ok, well, there are plenty of people on math zulips, at least in some fields.

Comment: https://mathblogging.org/ may provide some inspiration. Note the combination of Twitter (to promulgate the links) with blogging (to provide the content).

Comment: Try Quora. It has some qualified people there answering lay math questions.

Comment: I'm surprised that no-one has mentioned https://mathstodon.xyz/.